# Sequelize belongsToMany additional attributes in join table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, has-and-belongs-to-many, sequelize-cli

I'm having problem with an additional attribute in the join table of the belongsToMany relation.
In the set or add method this attribute is not being passed to mysql.

I'm following the documentation pass as "through" the attribute within the set method, but it is not working.
Would anyone know what could be wrong since following the documentation is not working?

Note: The registration and update of the join is correct, only the additional attribute that is not being passed to the table.

Functionality Model:

```
export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Functionality = sequelize.define('functionality', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      field: 'name',
      type: DataTypes.STRING(300),
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Functionality.belongsToMany(models.privilege, { as: 'privilegies', through: models.functionality_privilege, foreignKey: 'functionality_id' });
      }
    },
    tableName: 'functionality',
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'createdAt',
    updatedAt: 'updatedAt'
  });
  return Functionality;
}
```

Privilege Model:

```
export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Privilege = sequelize.define('privilege', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    name: {
      field: 'name',
      type: DataTypes.STRING(300),
      allowNull: false
    }
  }, {
    classMethods: {
      associate: function(models) {
        Privilege.belongsToMany(models.functionality, { as: 'functionalities', through: models.functionality_privilege, foreignKey: 'privilege_id' });
      }
    },
    tableName: 'privilege',
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'createdAt',
    updatedAt: 'updatedAt'
  });
  return Privilege;
}
```

FunctionalityPrivilege Model:

```
export default function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  const Functionalityprivilege = sequelize.define('functionality_privilege', {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER(11),
      allowNull: false,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    edit: {
      field: 'edit',
      type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN
    }
  }, {
    tableName: 'functionality_privilege',
    freezeTableName: true,
    timestamps: true,
    createdAt: 'created_at',
    updatedAt: 'updated_at'
  });
  return Functionalityprivilege;
}
```

Method Create:

```
create(options) {
    let obj = options.payload;
    return this.functionalityDao.create(obj)
    .then((result) => {
      return result.setPrivilegies(obj.privilegies, { through: { edit: obj.permissions }})
    });
  }
```

OR

```
return result.setPrivilegies(obj.privilegies, { through: { edit: true }})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't manage to do this with 'set' function but it worked for me with 'add' method:

```
result.addPrivilege(privilege, { through: { edit: true }});
```

It should work for the already existing privilege. It didn't work with the array of entities (privileges in your case), so I had to call 'add' method several times. Like this:

```
return Promise.all(
  privileges.map(privilege =>  result.addPrivilege(privilege, { through: { edit: true }}));
)
```