# Sequelize Many to Many Relationship using Through does not insert additional attributes

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a many to many relationship between: `Step` and `Control` Through `ControlsConfig`.
When creating a `Control` object and call `addStep` function and specify the additional attributes (which exist in the relation table), Sequelize creates the records in the relational table `ControlsConfig` **but the additional attributes are NULLs.**

PS: The tables are creating correctly in the database.

> Table 1: **Step**
>
> Table 2: **Control**
>
> Relation table: **ControlsConfig**

**Step**

```
 var Step = sequelize.define('Step', {
    title: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    description: DataTypes.STRING,
    type: { type: DataTypes.ENUM('task', 'approval'), allowNull: false, defaultValue: 'task' },
    order: DataTypes.INTEGER
  });

  Step.associate = function(models) {
    models.Step.belongsTo(models.User);
    models.Step.belongsTo(models.Template);
    models.Step.hasMany(models.Action);
  };
```

**Control**

```
var Control = sequelize.define('Control', {
    label: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
    order: { type: DataTypes.INTEGER },
    type: { type: DataTypes.ENUM('text', 'yes/no') },
    config: { type: DataTypes.TEXT },
    controlUiId: { type: DataTypes.STRING }
  });

  Control.associate = function(models) {
    models.Control.belongsTo(models.Section);
  };
```

**ControlsConfigs**

```
  module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var ControlsConfig = sequelize.define('ControlsConfig', {
    visibility: { type: DataTypes.ENUM('hidden', 'readonly', 'editable', 'required') },
    config: { type: DataTypes.TEXT }
  });

  ControlsConfig.associate = function(models) {
    models.Control.belongsToMany(models.Step, { through: models.ControlsConfig });
    models.Step.belongsToMany(models.Control, { through: models.ControlsConfig });
    models.ControlsConfig.belongsTo(models.Template);
  };

  return ControlsConfig;
};
```

**Insertion:**

```
try {
    var step1 = await Step.create({ /*bla bla*/ });        
    var control1 = await Control.create({ /*bla bla*/ });    
    var OK = await control1.addStep(step1, {through: { config: 'THIS FIELD ALWAYS APPEARS NULL' }});
  } catch (error) { /* No errors*/ }
```

I am following the same strategy stated at the [documentation](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#belongs-to-many-associations)

```
//If you want additional attributes in your join table, you can define a model for the join table in sequelize, before you define the association, and then tell sequelize that it should use that model for joining, instead of creating a new one:

const User = sequelize.define('user', {})
const Project = sequelize.define('project', {})
const UserProjects = sequelize.define('userProjects', {
    status: DataTypes.STRING
})

User.belongsToMany(Project, { through: UserProjects })
Project.belongsToMany(User, { through: UserProjects })

//To add a new project to a user and set its status, you pass extra options.through to the setter, which contains the attributes for the join table

user.addProject(project, { through: { status: 'started' }})
```

Comment: `/*bla bla*/` is actually the important part here. Did you even declare any of the schema attributes with `NOT NULL`? If you are unsure what that means, then you should actually include the schema definition you are omitting from the question.

Comment: Thanks @NeilLunn , I thought the attributes are irrelevant, I have modified the question and added the previously omitted code.

Comment: Well if the additional attributes are NULL then this is because you have not supplied any other values and did not explicitly forbid it in your schema definition above. SQL based RDMS do not just magically exclude table columns when you omit the data. You either supply it, set defaults or explicitly forbid it to force your code implementation to supply values.

Comment: @NeilLunn , Doesn't this line mean setting the value of "config" column which is one of the additional attributes but it becomes always null in the database?
var OK = await control1.addStep(step1, {through: { config: 'THIS FIELD ALWAYS APPEARS NULL' }});

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass `edit: true` to the addProject and addStep method.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195045/sequelize-belongstomany-additional-attributes-in-join-table) answer it has a similar issue

[Sequelize belongsToMany additional attributes in join table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49195045/sequelize-belongstomany-additional-attributes-in-join-table)

Comment: At the mentioned question, the additional attribute was for a column named "edit" that is why it is passed to the through object, but in my case, it is named "config" which did not work when passing it.